# Main window doesnt closes after caling new script from it

Tags: python, wxpython, subprocess

I am learning python and for GUI model using wxpython, as I am new to programing get stuck every time.
My issue is I have a GUI (main window)with two buttons,when user clicks button1 it opens sub window (seperate python script), I want to close or destroy main window before opening sub window.

```
      self.Destroy()
      subprocess.call("python newframe.py",shell=True)
      #It will not close main window
```

What will be the wrong i am trying to do , and please explain what is proper method.

Looking for suggestions thanks .
Sorry for my english .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` wait subprocess to exit. -> button callback will never return until subprogram exit. This keep main window to close. Use `subprocess.Popen()` which does not wait subprocess.

```
self.Destroy()
subprocess.Popen('python newframe.py', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't close the main frame or you'll actually exit the application. Instead you should Hide the main frame and just Show the sub-frame. Then when you close the sub-frame, you can re-show the main frame. I personally think using Pubsub is the easiest way to accomplish this. Here's a link to a tutorial that shows how to do it:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

You could also pass a reference to the main frame when you instantiate the sub-frame or call something like GetTopWindow() or GetParent(), but I really recommend Pubsub for this.